# Sympy will not compute this integral

Tags: python, sympy, integral, calculus

I'm trying to run the following sample in sympy

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

n, L, x = sp.symbols('n L x')    
sp.integrate(sp.cos(sp.pi*x/L)**2, (x, -L/2, L/2))
```

For some reason, it does not actually solve this integral. It just prints out the original integral.

```
>>> sp.integrate(sp.cos(sp.pi*x/L)**2, (x, -L/2, L/2))
  L
  -
  2
  /
 |
 |     2/pi*x\
 |  cos |----| dx
 |      \ L  /
 |
/
-L
---
 2
```

[Wolfram Alpha, on the other hand, does not have this issue.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20cos(n*pi*x%2FL)%5E2%20dx%20from%20-L%2F2%20to%20L%2F2)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Do not appreciate the sarcasm. Obviously this integral is computable, and SymPy is not doing it. Why is that the case?

Comment: There was no sarcasm. I can think of other questions you could be asking. You are more likely to get good answers here if you make your questions explicit and clear. It also helps to avoid criticizing the people trying to help you. You may want to delete your comment and add the relevant information to your main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a bit annoying, but sympy isn't evaluating the integral because it doesn't know enough about `L`.  Specifically, it is leaving the door open to the possibility `L=0`, which would wreak havoc on your integrand.  To overcome this we simply need to inform sympy that `L` is not zero.  The easiest way to do this is to pass an argument to `symbols` during instantiation:

```
import sympy as sp
n, x = sp.symbols('n x')    
L = sp.symbols('L', nonzero=True)
sp.integrate(sp.cos(sp.pi*x/L)**2, (x, -L/2, L/2))
#>>> L/2
```